# Master/Detail view: from Add view to Detail view and vice versa

Tags: ios, swift

This might be a very simple question, but I could not find a clear answer on how to achieve this properly (= elegantly).

I have a simple list (table view) of items (called models in the screenshot below). When I add a new item, I have a modal segue to display the `Add view`.
When hitting `Save`, this **currently** goes back to the table view.
In the list (table view), when hitting on an item, it shows the `detail view`.

**Whished behaviour**

1. When hitting `save` when adding a new item, the `detail view` should be shown, instead of going back to the list
2. When hitting `edit` in the `detail view`, it should show the `add (edit actually) view` for the user to modify the model

This is the same behaviour as the native iOS `Contacts` app.

Thanks in advance for the help, and sorry for the simplicity of the question!

[image: The navigation storyboard]

---

**Here is what I tried**

Using a Custom Segue on a duplicated segue for showing the details

```
class FadeSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        guard let destinationView = self.destination.view else {
            // Fallback to no fading
            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        destinationView.alpha = 0
        self.source.view?.addSubview(destinationView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: CATransaction.animationDuration(), animations: {
            destinationView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { _ in
            destinationView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

and on `Save` for the new model (in AddModelViewController), I call this in the list (table) ViewController:

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailViewSegueAfterNewModel", sender: nil)
})
```

Comment: Why not segue to the details when the Save button is pressed? What have you tried?

Comment: Because it does not animate as it does in the Contacts app when you add a new contact

Comment: In the contacts app, the Add Contact screen is presented modally. When a contact is added, the Contact Details screen for the newly added Contact are pushed in the UINavigationController stack. You can do the same thing using a completionBlock on the dismissal of the modally presented View Controller, no?

Comment: That's the idea, but doing so does not exactly result in what's whished. Even though the animated flag is false, you can shortly see the dismissal before the Details View is pushed :/

Comment: have you tried doing the dismissal in a completion block of the presentation?

Comment: I edited the question with some code to help the discussion

Comment: basically, what I need is a cross disolve animation between the modal VC and the pushed VC, without seeing the intermediate VC

Comment: Yes, that could work.